# l-value query in C

Tags: c, lvalue

I had confusion about the -l value and r-value.
consider the code

`int x;
   x=5;`

with

> int x

memory space is reserved for int variable. then, value 5 is assigned to it.
my question is

1. the declaration means that x is a l-value?
2. if x has address 0xyyyy in memory, &x refers to this address.Is this address 0xyyy
   the l-value i.e &x is the l-value? but , the address of var is pointer, so , then, l-value
   becomes pointer variable?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, an lvalue is just a fancy term for an expression that you can assign to. In other words, if something can appear on the left side of a = operator, it is an lvalue.  That means `x` is an lvalue, but `&x` is not - you can't re-assign the address of x to something else.

If you have a function like `int* getIntPtr()` then `getIntPtr()` isn't an lvalue (writing `getIntPtr() = 5` doesn't make any sense), but `*(getIntPtr())` is.

Edit: Apparently, it's not *quite* as easy. If x was defined as const, `x` would still be an lvalue (called a non-modifiable lvalue), even though you cannot assign to it. I'm not sure if there are other exceptions.

Comment: A closer approximation is that an lvalue is an expression that designates an object.  The flaw in *that* definition is that, given `int *ptr = NULL;`, `*ptr` is still an lvalue.

Comment: An array is also an lvalue but you cannot assign to it.

Answer (score 1):

An `l-value` makes sense on the left side of an assignment.  All `l-values` are also `r-values`.  Whether memory is needed or not has little to do with it being an `l-value`. More to the point is whether it evaluates to a memory location where something can be stored.

```
int  x = 3;

x+5 = 7;    // error
```

The expression `x+5` is not an `l-value`.

Comment: The C standard doesn't use the term "rvalue" except in one footnote, where it says that it's merely "the value of an expression" (whereas an lvalue is the expression itself, if the expression designates an object).  I personally find this a bit confusion, and inconsistent with the original meanings of the terms, but when discussing C it's best to use the term "lvalue" as the standard defines it.

Comment: @Keith Thompson:  I'm pretty sure K&R mention `lvalue` and `rvalue`, though `rvalue` is much less used.

Answer (score 1):

**lValue** => If you can take address of an expression, then it is a lValue.

```
10 = a; // Can we take the address of 10 ?
```

**rValue** => If you can not take the address of an express, then it is rValue.

```
a = 10;
```

There are still some exceptions. For example, array type is an **lValue** whose address cannot be taken though or assigned to.

```
int a[5] ;  // &a => Not valid
a = /* some thing */  // Not valid
```

Comment: `&a` not valid!? Isn't it the same than `a`?

Answer (score 0):

You guys are right, but I think there may be just a little more to the OP's question. This is also something that's bugged me too.

so

```
int x;
```

Now `x` is an lvalue. But what is *x* exactly? Is it a place in memory where you can store stuff? But wait... that would be `&x`, which isn't an lvalue.

Another strange thing, is that `x` doesn't have to even have a location in memory. The compiler might chose to leave it in a register the whole time. *Now* what makes it an lvalue?

I think the best way to summarize is that an `lvalue` is a concept the compiler uses, but that doesn't show up in the runtime. `x` might be an lvalue because the compiler knows it can

```
store $x %ax
```

(I make up assembly syntax; been too long)

Or maybe it's in a register and it knows it can

```
move %bx %ax
```

Basically, it's an lvalue because the compiler knows how to store something in "it", but you can't grab a hold of that "it".

Comment: this is not an answer, you're probably floating in the same lack of confidence as the op.

Comment: Is the question *really* just "what is an lvalue?" If it were I think they would have found an answer by now.

Comment: What is x exactly? It's a variable! In C, it is (conceptually) the name of a memory location where you can store values, with associated information about type and constness and maybe other things. &x is the *address* of that memory location. You can't store your information in the location's address. You store it in the location. Of course the compiler can optimize the code so the variable is only stored in a register, as long as the result behaves the same. But that doesn't change what the variable is conceptually.

Comment: Just to be clear, I meant "what is *x* exactly" rhetorically. If you've ever tried designing a language, this is not a trivial question.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear :
First, `int x` doesn't reserves the space for the variable, it just notifies the compiler about the variable. The space is reserved and assigned when the value is assigned to it, i.e when we do `x=5;`.

Now, the question of L-Value and R-Value :

L-Value : It is something to which a constant value can be assigned.
So, yes `x` is a L-Value. Because we can do `x=5;`.
But `&x` is not a L-Value since we can-not do `&x=5;`. Similarly, `0xyyyy` is the address and can be a R-Value but can-not be assigned so, it is not L-Value.

Comment: "int x doesn't reserves the space for the variable" Yes it does. Compile file t.c that contains only "int x;" and launch `nm t.o`.